# Textbox control in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working on a datagridview in C# in windows application. I want to add textbox controls in DataGridView. So, when we run it then textbox should be shown in gridview and we can put value in it and My grid has 3 columns and I want to add new row in grid when I press tab on 3rd column of gridview.

How do I do this?

Comment: The title for this question can be improved. Consider calling it something like: "Custom controls in DataGridView" instead of "Windows programming in C#.NET"

Comment: This should really be two questions, "How to insert a control into a gridview?" and "How to add a row on a grid view when a user tabs the third column?".

Comment: If you elaborated a bit on what your research has turned up so far, people here would be better placed to help. But I'm quite sure you cannot elaborate on that because you did not bother to research this.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to provide a precise answer since your question is lacking in detail and pretty general, but to get textboxes in your `DataGridView`, you're going to want to add some instances of [`DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxcolumn.aspx) to the `DataGridView`'s `Columns` collection. This will cause them to be populated with textboxes in each row.

To detect when the user presses tab on the 3rd column, you can add a 1-2 pixel wide fourth column and detect that it has recieved focus (almost definitely from a tab keystroke) using the `OnCellEnter` event.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So, for the "display textboxes by default portion of your question, here's the skinny:

On GridView->Edit Columns, add the columns you want to use explicitly. Then click on the link "Convert this field into a templateField". This will let you tweak the generated HTML for those cells. Say OK. Then go to GridView->Edit Templates. For your favorite Column, copy the ItemEditTemplate into the ItemTemplate. (ItemTemplate is the default. ItemEditTemplate contains the properly bound edit control.) Now all of your data fields will default to "editable."

I'm guessing you have a submit button. You'll need to tell the GridView to update the rows on submit., like so:

```
    For Each r As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim mon = System.Int32.Parse(CType(r.FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox).Text)
        If mon <> 0 Then GridView1.UpdateRow(r.RowIndex, False)
    Next
```

Obviously, you'll want different logic inside there, but the basic loop/findControl/updateRow logic should apply.

Microsoft has a walkthrough on this here: [Performing Bulk Updates to Rows Bound to a GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992036(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for example if you want to set your first column in `datagridview` as a `textbox` control:

```
private void dtgrdview_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        TextBox txtbox1=new TextBox();
        dtgrdview.Controls.Add(txtbox1);
        Rectangle rectangle = dtgrdview.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, e.RowIndex, true);
        txtbox1.Location = rectangle.Location;
        txtbox1.Size = rectangle.Size;                
        txtbox1.TextChanged += txtbox1_TextChanged; 
        txtbox1.Leave += txtbox1_Leave;                
        txtbox1.Visible = true;
    }

}
```

and don't forget to add this event in the same class as like below to call it when the cell have the focus:

```
private void txtbox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtbox1.Visible = false;
}

private void txtbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dtgrdview.CurrentCell.Value = txtbox1.Text;
}
```

If you have any other questions, don't hesitate to ask me :)