# How to set cells[i].controls C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, controls, cells

I have been developing an C# asp.Net project and now I have to transfer it to C# forms. It is my previous code for inserting textbox to a gridview cell :

```
TextBox a = new TextBox();
GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Controls.Add(a);
```

But surprisingly there is no `Cells[i].Controls` in WinForm. I don't want to add Controls to dataGridView and then locate them as if they were replaced the Cell. It works if there is no scrolling, but even then it is tricky and very possible to aware that textbox does not belong the cells when you selected an entire row.

I wonder if there is a simple way to add Controls like asp.net?

Sorry for bad English :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textbox control in DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871809/textbox-control-in-datagridview)

Comment: It is about adding new Column. I mean to insert a textbox to an existing Cell* (Not to add an entire Column with new Cells)

Comment: I think you can only do that when you subclass [DataGridViewCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell(v=vs.110).aspx)